# Server side Validation not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am configuring server side validation for my form.My problem is that when the control comes in the Areavalidator class

```
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Area.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```

from the above method the control again back to the controller class and in the error set it shows zero error.My question is that why it is not entering in the method where I am doing my validation stuff.
 @Override 
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

```
    Area object = (Area)target;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "areaName",
            "label.areaNameRequired");

   if(object.getAreaCode().length()==0)

    {
        {
            errors.rejectValue("areaCode", "label.areaCode", null);
        }

    }   

    }
```

The code in my controller class for validation

```
    @Autowired
    private AreaValidator areaValidator;

    @InitBinder("area")
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(areaValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveGridArea", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCountry(@ModelAttribute @Valid Area area,ModelMap map,BindingResult error) {

        if (error.hasErrors()) {
            return "area";
        }
```

Comment: Have you configured a LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean or a <mvc:annotation-driven /> element in your context.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you do `@Valid`, it is expected to have the corresponding `BindingResult` right next to the `modelAttribute`:
Here, your `ModelMap` is in between, making it impossible for the framework to associate the linked/associated errors to the `modelAttribute` .

You just need to change the order of your variable of the method.

Try this and it should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveGridArea", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCountry(@ModelAttribute @Valid Area area,BindingResult error, ModelMap map){
        ...
}
```